# QGIS: Edit attribute values of GeoJSON file: toggle editing greyed out

Tags: qgis, geojson

I'm trying to edit the values of attributes in QGIS, but it does not work. I tried to google an answer, but couldn't find anything so far. This is what I'm doing:

1. Open QGIS.
2. Drag in a GeoJSON file. It becomes a vector layer.
3. Menu bar > Layer > Toggle Editing.

I cannot toggle editing. It is greyed out. Am I missing something (I'm relatively new to QGIS)?

**QGGIS Version**

```
QGIS version
2.10.1-Pisa
QGIS code revision

Compiled against Qt
4.8.6
Running against Qt
4.8.6
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
1.11.2
Running against GDAL/OGR
1.11.2
Compiled against GEOS
3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2
Running against GEOS
3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
PostgreSQL Client Version
9.4.4
SpatiaLite Version
4.2.0
QWT Version
6.0.2
PROJ.4 Version
491
QScintilla2 Version
2.9
```

Comment: Has your Geojson mixed-properties features or mixed geometries? QGIS might not be able to write them back into the file. See http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html for the limitations of the driver.

Comment: @Kersten. It is, indeed. We can close this one as duplicate. I somehow missed that.